# Java 8 [cannot infer type variables] problem

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8, type-inference, method-reference

I have a `ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception>` functional interface with a single abstract method having this signature : `R apply(T t) throws E`.

I have a static utility method inside the functional interface that permits users converting `ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception>` instances into `Function<T, R>` instances :

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> unchecked (final ThrowingFunction<T, R, ?> tf)
{
    // code here
}
```

The problem here is why the type parameters `T` and `R` don't get inferred by the compiler if I pass the method reference `URL::new` into the `unchecked` static utility method ?

```
final URL url = unchecked(URL::new).apply("http://www.examples.com");
```

I mean, isn't `URL::new` a valid condidate for `ThrowingFunction<String, URL, MalformedURLException>` and therefore `T` and `R` should be inferred as `String` and `URL` respectively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it should work, it most probably has to do with the fact that you are using a method reference and the compiler is somehow getting confused, there are two solutions:

```
// a lambda
ThrowingFunction.unchecked((String x) -> new URL(x));


// an explicit cast
ThrowingFunction.unchecked((ThrowingFunction<String, URL, MalformedURLException>)URL::new);
```

Comment: Both answers seem fine to me, I chose the lambda approach as it is less explicit in terms of explicit type parameters feeding.

Comment: The problem is that `URL` has multiple constructors. You expect the compiler to select a constructor based on the expected function type while it needs to know the actual target constructor to determine the function type. In principle, considering the arity would be already enough to determine the right combination, but the current Java language does not do that. So, in contrast, `URL url = unchecked(URI::create) .andThen(unchecked(URI::toURL)) .apply("http://www.examples.com");` will work, as there is only one `URI::create` method…

Comment: @Holger and when you think that I've actually answered a few questions about this.. :| thank you

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what the issue is but the answer is `yes`, it is a valid candidate and it works if you split it into two statements:

```
ThrowingFunction<String, URL, MalformedURLException> ctor = URL::new;
final URL url = unchecked(ctor).apply("http://www.examples.com");
```

Comment: if you split, all the types are known and are explicit, this has to do with method reference not being able to infer the types